# CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType return Subscription start date is required

Tags: java, paypal

I am using merchant api as followed by this link [PayPal Integration guide](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_cc?interactive=ON&env=sandbox)

maven dependency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>merchantsdk</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.109</version>
</dependency>
```

my implementation is as follows,

```
CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq createRecurringPaymentsProfileReq = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq();
            CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestType();
            RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType recurringPaymentsProfileDetails = new RecurringPaymentsProfileDetailsType();
            recurringPaymentsProfileDetails.setBillingStartDate(formatterR.format(new Date()));
            recurringPaymentsProfileDetails.setSubscriberName(subs.getFirstName()+" "+subs.getLastName());

            BasicAmountType billingAmount = new BasicAmountType(CurrencyCodeType.USD, subs.getAmount().toString());
            BillingPeriodDetailsType paymentPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType(
                    BillingPeriodType.MONTH, Integer.parseInt("12"), billingAmount);

            ScheduleDetailsType scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetailsType("description", paymentPeriod); // description, paymentPeriod object
            CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetailsType(
                    recurringPaymentsProfileDetails, scheduleDetails);

            AddressType addressType = new AddressType();
            addressType.setStateOrProvince(subs.getState());
            addressType.setCityName(subs.getCity());
            addressType.setCountryName(subs.getCountry());

            PersonNameType personName = new PersonNameType();
            personName.setFirstName(subs.getFirstName());
            personName.setLastName(subs.getLastName());

            PayerInfoType payerInfoType = new PayerInfoType();
            payerInfoType.setAddress(addressType);
            payerInfoType.setPayerName(personName);

            CreditCardDetailsType creditCard = new CreditCardDetailsType();
            //creditCard.setCreditCardType(CreditCardTypeType.VISA);

            // Credit Card Number
            creditCard.setCreditCardNumber(subs.getCreditCardNo());//4442662639546634

            // Credit Card Expiration Month
            creditCard.setExpMonth(Integer.parseInt(subs.getExpirationDate().split("/")[0]));//Integer.parseInt("12")

            // Credit Card Expiration Year
            creditCard.setExpYear(Integer.parseInt(subs.getExpirationDate().split("/")[1]));//Integer.parseInt("2016")
            creditCard.setCVV2(subs.getCardCode());
            creditCard.setCardOwner(payerInfoType);
            createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails.setCreditCard(creditCard);

            createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest
                    .setCreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails(createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails);
            createRecurringPaymentsProfileReq
                    .setCreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest(createRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest);

            PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = null;
            try {
                service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService(sdkConfig);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("Error Message : " + e.getMessage());
            }
            CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse = null;
            try {
                // ## Making API call
                // Invoke the appropriate method corresponding to API in service
                // wrapper object
                 createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse = service
                        .createRecurringPaymentsProfile(createRecurringPaymentsProfileReq);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.info("Error Message : " + e.getMessage());
            }

            // ## Accessing response parameters
            // You can access the response parameters using getter methods in
            // response object as shown below
            // ### Success values
            if (createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse.getAck().getValue()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

                // A unique identifier for future reference to the details of
                // this recurring payment.
                LOGGER.info("Profile ID:"
                        + createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse
                                .getCreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetails()
                                .getProfileID());
                return "approved";
            }
            // ### Error Values
            // Access error values from error list using getter methods
            else {
                List<ErrorType> errorList = createRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse
                        .getErrors();
                LOGGER.info("API Error Message : "
                        + errorList.get(0).getLongMessage());
                return "error";
            }
```

It returns as follows,

```
Sep 02, 2014 12:16:37 PM com.paypal.core.LoggingManager log
```

INFO: 2014-09-02T06:46:37ZFailure6836cf5983224Start Date is requiredSubscription start date is required11549Error109.012566246
[ INFO] [http-8080-6 12:16:37] (TestPayment.java:subscriptionPayment:645) API Error Message : Subscription start date is required

Anyone, Please help me to fix this...

Comment: Can you post a sample of the raw API request that is getting sent?

Comment: I use my sandbox credential as mentioned in the this link -https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_cc?interactive=ON&env=sandbox, I also update the question with full code..

Comment: The code doesn't help much (at least not for quick review.)  I just need to see the actual API request getting generated from the code.

Comment: It seems that you are not passing the ProfileStartdate in the correct format . The correct format should be like "2013-08-24T05:38:48Z" . You can refer the link below for more info : https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: I fix that issue, it causes due to ProfileStartdate format issue as mentioned by @Eshan... Thank you guys for the reply... Thanks Andrew Angell