# Some of fields is missed out in recurring payment profile after making CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType response

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

After making the createRecurringPaymentProfileResponseType api call as [mentioned in my previous question CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619155/createrecurringpaymentsprofileresponsetype-return-subscription-start-date-is-req?noredirect=1#comment40051411_25619155) i get created the Recurring profile in my sandbox account but some of the field are not set... I attached the screen-shot from my paypal-sandbox account.. How to set the missed out fields, please help me to fix that...

[image]

API Request Made,

```
INFO: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes"><soapenv:Header><ns:RequesterCredentials><ebl:Credentials><ebl:Username>sandbox testing id</ebl:Username><ebl:Password>1408690256</ebl:Password><ebl:Signature>VALUE</ebl:Signature></ebl:Credentials></ns:RequesterCredentials></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ns:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq><ns:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest><ebl:Version>109.0</ebl:Version><ebl:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails><ebl:CreditCard><ebl:CreditCardNumber>4745425765192217</ebl:CreditCardNumber><ebl:ExpMonth>9</ebl:ExpMonth><ebl:ExpYear>2014</ebl:ExpYear><ebl:CardOwner><ebl:PayerName><ebl:FirstName>Annamalai</ebl:FirstName><ebl:LastName>Lk</ebl:LastName></ebl:PayerName><ebl:Address><ebl:Name></ebl:Name><ebl:CityName>canada</ebl:CityName><ebl:StateOrProvince>NY</ebl:StateOrProvince><ebl:CountryName>IN</ebl:CountryName></ebl:Address></ebl:CardOwner><ebl:CVV2>962</ebl:CVV2></ebl:CreditCard><ebl:RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails><ebl:SubscriberName>null Lk</ebl:SubscriberName><ebl:BillingStartDate>2014-09-03T10:50:29:029UTC</ebl:BillingStartDate></ebl:RecurringPaymentsProfileDetails><ebl:ScheduleDetails><ebl:Description>description</ebl:Description><ebl:PaymentPeriod><ebl:BillingPeriod>Month</ebl:BillingPeriod><ebl:BillingFrequency>12</ebl:BillingFrequency><ebl:Amount currencyID="USD">100</ebl:Amount></ebl:PaymentPeriod></ebl:ScheduleDetails></ebl:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails></ns:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest></ns:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Return Response as follows:

```
INFO: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><SOAP-ENV:Header><Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType"></Security><RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType"><Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType"><Username xsi:type="xs:string"></Username><Password xsi:type="xs:string"></Password><Signature xsi:type="xs:string"></Signature><Subject xsi:type="xs:string"></Subject></Credentials></RequesterCredentials></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0"><CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2014-09-03T10:50:33Z</Timestamp><Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Success</Ack><CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">4fcd7b1fa45e</CorrelationID><Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">109.0</Version><Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">12566246</Build><CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetails xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetailsType"><ProfileID xsi:type="xs:string">I-SJN77561P75U</ProfileID><ProfileStatus xsi:type="ebl:RecurringPaymentsProfileStatusType">ActiveProfile</ProfileStatus><TransactionID xsi:type="xs:string"></TransactionID></CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponseDetails></CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Need to see a sample of the API request that was used to create this profile.

Comment: Please check the post, I updated it with the API Request...

Answer (score 1):

Your request doesn't include the email address, so that's why it's not showing up in the PayPal profile.  Also, your request is setup to do 1 payment of $100 every 12 months.  Is that really what you wanted?

The amount fields are blank because it looks like a payment simply wasn't made against the profile yet.  The profile is created, but not money has been paid on it, so there's nothing to show there yet.  Once a payment does come through those would get updated.

Comment: Andrew Angell, Thanks for the reply.
I understand, i have following questions
1. where or in which setter i need to set the email id.?
2. I need the recurrence to be on each month, if i set it to 1 month it will works ?
3. In test mode, those field never update or when will it get updated ?

Comment: The email address goes in the "Payer" element.  Refer to the [API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_SOAP/) for more details.  For every month the frequency should just be 1.

Comment: I use like below,
PayerInfoType payerInfoType = new PayerInfoType();    payerInfoType.setPayer("email id");

but it is not setting the email id in recurrence profile.
Did i missing anything, please let me know how to fix it.